# How to load full size image to imageview

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera-intent

I try to build the simple "cameraIntet" and load the full size image from that camera to imageview, i build the same code like the example from the documentation (at full size image documentation)
  https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

And this js my onActivityResult code

```
  Override fun onActivityResult(...){
         Super.onActivityResults(...)
          If(requestCode == 1){
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath)
                Img_imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
           }
     }
```

And when i run the code and then take the picture, imageview just blank and not showing the picture,

So, how to show the full size image to imageview?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe want to try https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view
It can handle very large images.